# Nested models not created as batman objects

Tags: associations, batman.js

Given the following models with one-to-many relationship:

```
class App.Post extends Batman.Model
  @hasMany 'comments'

class App.Comment extends Batman.Model
  @belongsTo 'post'
```

My comments are included in the JSON of the post from the backend. Since i'm having `@encode 'comments'` the comments are added to the post. However, they are added in an array of simple JS objects instead of an associationset of Batman objects.

Should I really decode them explicitly like this

```
@encode 'comments',
  decode: (value, key, incomingJSON, outgoingAttributes, record) ->
    outgoingAttributes = App.Comment.createMultipleFromJSON(incomingJSON.comments)
```

or am I doing something stupid here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@hasMany "comments"` should automatically set up an encoder to load `comments` from JSON.

Did you mention that you added your own encoder, like

```
@encode 'comments'
```

?

If so, that is overriding the one created by `@hasMany 'comments'`. Try removing the `@encode 'comments'`. Does that help?